# my first seleniumscript is not working. error shows in import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; and ChromeDriver

Tags: google-chrome, import, webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QyYQ.png) screenshot of the error. I put Latest stable version 4.16.1 selenium server. But still error happening

I want to overcome the error and launch chrome driver when I run the code. package first;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Open_WebDrive {

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     
      ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198). There's an error with your `import` statement, but without seeing what that error is we can't really help. I'm not a Java developer but I suspect you might want to include chromedriver.exe in your project rather than selenium-server-*.jar? You may also want to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).